# UE detects and read MIB but not SIB-1 & directly send attach request to network that causes fail to attach

Tags: lte

newer UEs like Samsung s21 or higher versions, detect and read MIB but not SIB-1 & directly send attach request to network that cause fail to attach.
below is trace result:

Frame 2: 73 bytes on wire (584 bits), 73 bytes captured (584 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 13337, Dst Port: 4729
GSM TAP Header, ARFCN: 1650 (Downlink), TS: 0, Channel: AGCH (0)
Version: 3
Header Length: 28 bytes
Payload Type: LTE RRC (13)
Time Slot: 0
..00 0110 0111 0010 = ARFCN: **XXXX (removed for Privacy)**
.0.. .... .... .... = Uplink: 0
0... .... .... .... = PCS band indicator: 0
Signal Level: 0 dBm
Signal/Noise Ratio: 0 dB
GSM Frame Number: 0
Antenna Number: 0
Sub-Slot: 0
LTE Radio Resource Control (RRC) protocol
BCCH-BCH-Message
message
dl-Bandwidth: n50 (3)
phich-Config
phich-Duration: normal (0)
phich-Resource: one (2)
systemFrameNumber: f6 [bit length 8, 1111 0110 decimal value 246]
schedulingInfoSIB1-BR-r13: SystemInformationBlockType1-BR is not scheduled (0)
...0 .... systemInfoUnchanged-BR-r15: False
partEARFCN-17: spare (0)
spare: 00 [bit length 2, 6 LSB pad bits, 00.. .... decimal value 0]
spare: 00 [bit length 1, 7 LSB pad bits, 0... .... decimal value 0]

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCeL0.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzzBY.jpg)

GSM TAP Header, ARFCN: 1650 (Downlink), TS: 0, Channel: UNKNOWN (0)
Version: 3
Header Length: 28 bytes
Payload Type: LTE NAS (18)
Time Slot: 0
..00 0110 0111 0010 = ARFCN: 1650
.0.. .... .... .... = Uplink: 0
0... .... .... .... = PCS band indicator: 0
Signal Level: 0 dBm
Signal/Noise Ratio: 0 dB
GSM Frame Number: 0
Antenna Number: 0
Sub-Slot: 0
Non-Access-Stratum (NAS)PDU
0000 .... = Security header type: Plain NAS message, not security protected (0)
.... 0111 = Protocol discriminator: EPS mobility management messages (0x7)
NAS EPS Mobility Management Message Type: Attach request (0x41)
0... .... = Type of security context flag (TSC): Native security context (for KSIasme or KSIamf)
.111 .... = NAS key set identifier: No key is available (7)
.... 0... = Spare bit(s): 0x00
.... .010 = EPS attach type: Combined EPS/IMSI attach (2)
EPS mobile identity
Length: 8
.... 1... = Odd/even indication: Odd number of identity digits
.... .001 = Type of identity: IMSI (1)
IMSI: XXXXX (removed for privacy)
[Association IMSI: **XXXXX (removed for privacy)]**
Mobile Country Code (MCC): **XXXXX (removed for privacy)**
Mobile Network Code (MNC): **XXXXX (removed for privacy)**
UE network capability
Length: 7
1... .... = EEA0: Supported
.1.. .... = 128-EEA1: Supported
..1. .... = 128-EEA2: Supported
...1 .... = 128-EEA3: Supported
.... 0... = EEA4: Not supported
.... .0.. = EEA5: Not supported
.... ..0. = EEA6: Not supported
.... ...0 = EEA7: Not supported
0... .... = EIA0: Not supported
.1.. .... = 128-EIA1: Supported
..1. .... = 128-EIA2: Supported
...1 .... = 128-EIA3: Supported
.... 0... = EIA4: Not supported
.... .0.. = EIA5: Not supported
.... ..0. = EIA6: Not supported
.... ...0 = EIA7: Not supported
0... .... = UEA0: Not supported
.0.. .... = UEA1: Not supported
..0. .... = UEA2: Not supported
...0 .... = UEA3: Not supported
.... 0... = UEA4: Not supported
.... .0.. = UEA5: Not supported
.... ..0. = UEA6: Not supported
.... ...0 = UEA7: Not supported
0... .... = UCS2 support (UCS2): The UE has a preference for the default alphabet
.0.. .... = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA1: Not supported
..0. .... = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA2: Not supported
...0 .... = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA3: Not supported
.... 0... = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA4: Not supported
.... .0.. = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA5: Not supported
.... ..0. = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA6: Not supported
.... ...0 = UMTS integrity algorithm UIA7: Not supported
0... .... = ProSe direct discovery: Not supported
.0.. .... = ProSe: Not supported
..0. .... = H.245 After SRVCC Handover: Not supported
...1 .... = Access class control for CSFB: Supported
.... 1... = LTE Positioning Protocol: Supported
.... .0.. = Location services (LCS) notification mechanisms: Not supported
.... ..0. = SRVCC from E-UTRAN to cdma2000 1xCS: Not supported
.... ...0 = Notification procedure: Not supported
0... .... = Extended protocol configuration options: Not supported
.0.. .... = Header compression for control plane CIoT EPS optimization: Not supported
..0. .... = EMM-REGISTERED w/o PDN connectivity: Not supported
...0 .... = S1-U data transfer: Not supported
.... 0... = User plane CIoT EPS optimization: Not supported
.... .0.. = Control plane CIoT EPS optimization: Not supported
.... ..0. = ProSe UE-to-network relay: Not supported
.... ...0 = ProSe direct communication: Not supported
1... .... = Signalling for a maximum number of 15 EPS bearer contexts: Supported
.0.. .... = Service gap control: Not supported
..0. .... = N1 mode: Not supported
...0 .... = Dual connectivity with NR: Not supported
.... 0... = Control plane data backoff: Not supported
.... .0.. = Restriction on use of enhanced coverage: Not supported
.... ..0. = V2X communication over PC5: Not supported
.... ...0 = Multiple DRB: Not supported
ESM message container
Length: 59
ESM message container contents: 0222d031d127348080211001000010810600000000830600000000000d00000300000a00…
0000 .... = EPS bearer identity: No EPS bearer identity assigned (0)
.... 0010 = Protocol discriminator: EPS session management messages (0x2)
Procedure transaction identity: 34
NAS EPS session management messages: PDN connectivity request (0xd0)
0011 .... = PDN type: IPv4v6 (3)
.... 0001 = Request type: Initial request (1)
ESM information transfer flag
1101 .... = Element ID: 0xd-
.... 000. = Spare bit(s): 0x00
.... ...1 = EIT (ESM information transfer): Security protected ESM information transfer required
Protocol Configuration Options
Element ID: 0x27
Length: 52
[Link direction: MS to network (0)]
1... .... = Extension: True
.... .000 = Configuration Protocol: PPP for use with IP PDP type or IP PDN type (0)
Protocol or Container ID: Internet Protocol Control Protocol (0x8021)
Length: 0x10 (16)
PPP IP Control Protocol
Code: Configuration Request (1)
Identifier: 0 (0x00)
Length: 16
Options: (12 bytes), Primary DNS Server IP Address, Secondary DNS Server IP Address
Primary DNS Server IP Address
Type: Primary DNS Server IP Address (129)
Length: 6
Primary DNS Address: 0.0.0.0
Secondary DNS Server IP Address
Type: Secondary DNS Server IP Address (131)
Length: 6
Secondary DNS Address: 0.0.0.0
Protocol or Container ID: DNS Server IPv4 Address Request (0x000d)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: DNS Server IPv6 Address Request (0x0003)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: IP address allocation via NAS signalling (0x000a)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: MS Support of Network Requested Bearer Control indicator (0x0005)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: IPv4 Link MTU Request (0x0010)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: MS support of Local address in TFT indicator (0x0011)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: 3GPP PS data off UE status (0x0017)
Length: 0x01 (1)
3GPP PS data off UE status: Deactivated (1)
Protocol or Container ID: PDU session ID (0x001a)
Length: 0x01 (1)
PDU session identity: PDU session identity value 1 (1)
Protocol or Container ID: QoS rules with the length of two octets support indicator (0x0023)
Length: 0x00 (0)
Protocol or Container ID: QoS flow descriptions with the length of two octets support indicator (0x0024)
Length: 0x00 (0)
DRX Parameter
Element ID: 0x5c
SPLIT PG CYCLE CODE: 10 (10)
0000 .... = CN Specific DRX cycle length coefficient: CN Specific DRX cycle length coefficient / value not specified by the MS (0)
.... 0... = SPLIT on CCCH: Split pg cycle on CCCH is not supported by the mobile station
.... .000 = Non-DRX timer: no non-DRX mode after transfer state (0)
TMSI Status
1001 .... = Element ID: 0x9-
.... 000. = Spare bit(s): 0
.... ...0 = TMSI flag: no valid TMSI available
Mobile station classmark 2
Element ID: 0x11
Length: 3
0... .... = Spare: 0
.10. .... = Revision Level: Used by mobile stations supporting R99 or later versions of the protocol (2)
...0 .... = ES IND: Controlled Early Classmark Sending option is not implemented in the MS
.... 1... = A5/1 algorithm supported: encryption algorithm A5/1 not available
.... .111 = RF Power Capability: RF Power capability is irrelevant in this information element (7)
0... .... = Spare: 0
.0.. .... = PS capability (pseudo-synchronization capability): PS capability not present
..01 .... = SS Screening Indicator: Capability of handling of ellipsis notation and phase 2 error handling  (1)
.... 1... = SM capability (MT SMS pt to pt capability): Mobile station supports mobile terminated point to point SMS
.... .0.. = VBS notification reception: no VBS capability or no notifications wanted
.... ..0. = VGCS notification reception: no VGCS capability or no notifications wanted
.... ...0 = FC Frequency Capability: The MS does not support the E-GSM or R-GSM band
1... .... = CM3: The MS supports options that are indicated in classmark 3 IE
.0.. .... = Spare: 0
..1. .... = LCS VA capability (LCS value added location request notification capability): LCS value added location request notification capability supported
...0 .... = UCS2 treatment: the ME has a preference for the default alphabet
.... 0... = SoLSA: The ME does not support SoLSA
.... .1.. = CMSP: CM Service Prompt: Network initiated MO CM connection request supported for at least one CM protocol
.... ..1. = A5/3 algorithm supported: encryption algorithm A5/3 available
.... ...0 = A5/2 algorithm supported: encryption algorithm A5/2 not available
Additional update type
1111 .... = Element ID: 0xf-
.... 00.. = Preferred CIoT network behaviour: No additional information (0)
.... ..0. = SAF: Keeping the NAS signalling connection is not required after the completion of the tracking area updating procedure
.... ...1 = AUTV: SMS only
Voice Domain Preference and UE's Usage Setting
Element ID: 0x5d
Length: 1
0000 0... = Spare bit(s): 0
.... .0.. = UE's usage setting: Voice centric
.... ..11 = Voice domain preference for E-UTRAN: IMS PS voice preferred, CS Voice as secondary (3)
MS network feature support
1100 .... = Element ID: 0xc-
.... 000. = Spare bit(s): 0
.... ...1 = Extended periodic timers: MS supports the extended periodic timer in this domain

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to know the cause of not reading SIB-1 and which eventual parameter(s) should be modified in Network?